# Failed to 'make' when installing gr-mediatools

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnuradio

The gr-mediatools could be find from [here](https://github.com/iMatrix67/gr-mediatools) . The result of 'cmake': 
 Something like:

```
Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property
...
get_target_property() called with non-existent target
```

There may has some problem result in the fail of 'make'. I don't know it quite  well.

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
Checking for GNU Radio Module: RUNTIME
-- Checking for module 'gnuradio-runtime'
--   Found gnuradio-runtime, version 3.7.9
 * INCLUDES=/usr/include
 * LIBS=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-runtime.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-pmt.so
-- Found GNURADIO_RUNTIME: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-runtime.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-pmt.so  
GNURADIO_RUNTIME_FOUND = TRUE
Checking for GNU Radio Module: BLOCKS
-- Checking for module 'gnuradio-blocks'
--   Found gnuradio-blocks, version 3.7.9
 * INCLUDES=/usr/include
 * LIBS=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-blocks.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-runtime.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-pmt.so
-- Found GNURADIO_BLOCKS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-blocks.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-runtime.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-pmt.so  
GNURADIO_BLOCKS_FOUND = TRUE
Checking for GNU Radio Module: PMT
-- Checking for module 'gnuradio-runtime'
--   Found gnuradio-runtime, version 3.7.9
 * INCLUDES=/usr/include
 * LIBS=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-runtime.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-pmt.so
-- Found GNURADIO_PMT: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-runtime.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-pmt.so  
GNURADIO_PMT_FOUND = TRUE
-- 
-- Checking for module SWIG
-- Found SWIG version 3.0.8.
-- Found SWIG: /usr/bin/swig3.0  
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2") 
-- Performing Test HAVE_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GrTest.cmake:45 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  **The LOCATION property should not be read from target "gnuradio-mediatools".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.**

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  python/CMakeLists.txt:44 (GR_ADD_TEST)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GrTest.cmake:45 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "/usr/bin/python2".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  python/CMakeLists.txt:44 (GR_ADD_TEST)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GrTest.cmake:45 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target
  "/home/imatrix/
  RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/python/qa_mediatools_audiosource_s.py".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  python/CMakeLists.txt:44 (GR_ADD_TEST)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.11") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/build
```

The result of 'make -j4' Error like:‘avcodec_alloc_frame’ was not declared in this scope,AVStream::codec’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations] It seems
like that the ' gr-mediatools' it too old,should i use the old GNUradio? How could I fix problem like'AVStream::codec’ is deprecated'?
thanks in advance!

```
Scanning dependencies of target pygen_python_86ad7
Scanning dependencies of target pygen_apps_9a6dd
Scanning dependencies of target mediatools_swig_swig_doc
Scanning dependencies of target gnuradio-mediatools
[  0%] Built target pygen_apps_9a6dd
[  0%] Built target mediatools_swig_swig_doc
[  5%] Generating __init__.pyc
[ 11%] Generating __init__.pyo
Scanning dependencies of target _mediatools_swig_swig_tag
[ 17%] Building CXX object swig/CMakeFiles/_mediatools_swig_swig_tag.dir/_mediatools_swig_swig_tag.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-mediatools.dir/mediatools_audiosource_s.cc.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-mediatools.dir/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc.o
[ 35%] Linking CXX executable _mediatools_swig_swig_tag
[ 35%] Built target pygen_python_86ad7
[ 35%] Built target _mediatools_swig_swig_tag
[ 41%] Generating mediatools_swig.tag
Scanning dependencies of target mediatools_swig_swig_2d0df
[ 47%] Building CXX object swig/CMakeFiles/mediatools_swig_swig_2d0df.dir/mediatools_swig_swig_2d0df.cpp.o
[ 52%] Linking CXX executable mediatools_swig_swig_2d0df
Swig source
[ 52%] Built target mediatools_swig_swig_2d0df
Scanning dependencies of target pygen_swig_52046
[ 58%] Generating mediatools_swig.pyo
[ 64%] Generating mediatools_swig.pyc
[ 70%] Built target pygen_swig_52046
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc: In member function ‘bool mediatools_audiosource_impl::open(std::__cxx11::string)’:
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:42:58: warning: ‘AVStream::codec’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         d_codec_ctx = d_format_ctx->streams[stream_idx]->codec;
                                                          ^
In file included from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/include/mediatools_audiosource_impl.h:11:0,
                 from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:893:21: note: declared here
     AVCodecContext *codec;
                     ^
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:42:58: warning: ‘AVStream::codec’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         d_codec_ctx = d_format_ctx->streams[stream_idx]->codec;
                                                          ^
In file included from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/include/mediatools_audiosource_impl.h:11:0,
                 from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:893:21: note: declared here
     AVCodecContext *codec;
                     ^
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:42:58: warning: ‘AVStream::codec’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         d_codec_ctx = d_format_ctx->streams[stream_idx]->codec;
                                                          ^
In file included from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/include/mediatools_audiosource_impl.h:11:0,
                 from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:893:21: note: declared here
     AVCodecContext *codec;
                     ^
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc: In member function ‘void mediatools_audiosource_impl::readData(std::vector<short int>&)’:
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:91:39: error: ‘avcodec_alloc_frame’ was not declared in this scope
         d_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                                       ^
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:95:14: warning: ‘int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext*, AVFrame*, int*, const AVPacket*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     int rc = avcodec_decode_audio4(d_codec_ctx, d_frame, &got_frame, &d_packet);   
              ^
In file included from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/include/mediatools_audiosource_impl.h:10:0,
                 from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4817:5: note: declared here
 int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame,
     ^
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:95:14: warning: ‘int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext*, AVFrame*, int*, const AVPacket*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     int rc = avcodec_decode_audio4(d_codec_ctx, d_frame, &got_frame, &d_packet);   
              ^
In file included from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/include/mediatools_audiosource_impl.h:10:0,
                 from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4817:5: note: declared here
 int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame,
     ^
/home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:95:79: warning: ‘int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext*, AVFrame*, int*, const AVPacket*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     int rc = avcodec_decode_audio4(d_codec_ctx, d_frame, &got_frame, &d_packet);   
                                                                               ^
In file included from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/include/mediatools_audiosource_impl.h:10:0,
                 from /home/imatrix/ RadioML/dataset-master/gr-mediatools-master/lib/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4817:5: note: declared here
 int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame,
     ^
lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-mediatools.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-mediatools.dir/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-mediatools.dir/mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for .. undone....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:135: recipe for target 'lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-mediatools.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-mediatools.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like gr-mediatools is out of date. File an issue on github at the original project.

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43069374/6654146 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the offending line

```
d_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
```

in mediatools_audiosource_impl.cc with:

```
d_frame = av_frame_alloc();
```

I was able successfully install gr-mediatools after the change.

Thanks

Comment: did this still got  a lot of errors. "cmake Error variables are used in this project , but they are set to NOTFOUND"